# jquery .prev() yields undefined

Tags: jquery

This question is asked before but the answer given does not help me figure out why the following code does not work:

```
$.fn.humanCheck = function(){
      var user_answer = this.val();
      var real_answer = this.prev("#captcha-real").val();
      alert(user_answer + " or " + real_answer);
      if(real_answer != user_answer || user_answer === ""){
        this.val("");
        $('span#required').text('To prove that you are human, please provide a valid answer above');
      }
      return this;
    };
```

The variable real_answer yields "undefined" why?

Here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/rj32ay37/11/

The issue here is that I have 7 forms on the same page they all use the same captcha form group. So there are multiple `input#captcha-user` and `input#captcha-real` on the page. The question and answer is generated randomly with php `mt_rand()`. So when user fills the user_answer field, the answer should match the real_answer field above it

Thanks for you help

Comment: Because `#captcha-real` is not a sibling of `#captcha-user`

Comment: Did you read [the docs for `.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)?  It's for DOM traversal, finding the immediate preceding sibling of the target selector... not for getting the previous value.  Otherwise, if you already understood this, then it's because you don't have any siblings previous to your target selector.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `prev`(you don't use it correct anyway). Your element has ID(that must be unique of course):

```
var real_answer = $("#captcha-real").val();
```

Comment: edited my question above sorry

Comment: You have multiple elements with same id(`#captcha-real`)?